# converting an rdd out of DF column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I made an RDD from a DF column

```
##converting a column into an rdd
rdd = eDF_review_split.select('splReview').rdd.map(list)
##print rdd.take(10)
```

The result I got was as follow

```
[[u'Installing'], [u'the'], [u'game'], [u'was'], [u'a'], [u'struggle'], [u'(because'], [u'of'], [u'games'], [u'for']]
```

which makes sense because these words are from different rows.

How do I make it into a format which is like the following?

```
[u'Installing', u'the', u'game', u'was', u'a', u'struggle', u'(because', u'of', u'games', u'for']
```

I need to do that so I can do a proper word count.

Comment: What is the schema of `eDF_review_split`? can you provide a sampled data?

Comment: Why flatten your list for a simple word count?  You can perform a reduce for that in parallel

Answer (score 3):

[`flatMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap):

> `flatMap(f, preservesPartitioning=False)`
>
> Return a new RDD by first applying a function to all elements of this RDD, and then flattening the results.

with [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function):

```
df_review_split.select('splReview').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

> I need to do that so I can do a proper word count.

```
 eDF_review_split.groupBy('splReview').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse through the list of lists, and for each list inside the main list, append the values to another list.

One liner:

```
list_main_separated = [item for insideList in rdd for item in insideList]
```

This means:

```
list_main_separated = []

for insideList in rdd:
    for item in insideList :
        list_main_separated .append(item )
```

Comment: yeah I think this should work but bcuz my rdd is big its skipping the task

PS. bcuz I get 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable I am adding rdd.toLocalIterator()